# Why can I not pass 'this' to an inner class's method in this case?

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I have a class containing an inner class that looks somewhat like this:

```
class Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
    public:
        void update(const Foo& f)
        {
            //Updates using public getters of Foo
        }
    };
public:
    void doStuff() const
    {
        b_.update(*this);
    }
private:
    Bar b_;
};
```

The line `b_.update(*this)` is currently giving me the error `cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Foo::Bar' to 'Foo::Bar &'`

Why is that? The `update` method's parameter is of type `const Foo&`, meaning it couldn't possibly modify the `Foo` object if it wanted to. Shouldn't that satisfy the const method `doStuff`?

I've tried googling for someone having the same problem for an hour but I can't seem to word it correctly in order to find a similar question.

Is what I'm trying to do possible, or do I need to change my design?

Comment: [Clang has a great error message](https://godbolt.org/z/YPqr3MPr3).

Comment: It appears `doStuff` method should not be marked `const`.

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't have a notion of "inner class". There's a Java thing with that name, and there is nothing in C++ that does what that does. Usually `Bar` is referred to as a **nested** class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`doStuff` is `const` therefore `b_` is also `const` in this context so calling the non-const `update` function is not allowed.

If `doStuff` needs to modify `b_` it should not be marked `const`, you could mark `b_` as `mutable` but that's rarely the correct thing to do.

Comment: Had never heard of the keyword `mutable` before. Declaring `b_` as `mutable` did indeed solve the issue, but I understand that it's not ideal. A method marked `const` should never modify members. Do you think the usage is acceptable if the functionality of the `b_` member is only ever used inside `Foo` to help with some calculations? Or should I change my design so that `Bar` is not a nested class but declared outside `Foo`?

Comment: The only really valid use of `mutable` is for things like caches where calling an accessor method (which you'd expect to be `const`) needs to be able to update a cached value, that value therefore needs to be `mutable`. If calling a method makes no externally visible changes to the class then its probably reasonable to mark it `const` and have `mutable` members if necessary. `Bar` being a nested class makes no difference to this behaviour.